# Alternative to Datediff over()?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have data of this form:

```
user_id   event   started   ended   date
1         started 1         0       3/1/2018
1         ended   0         1       3/2/2018
2         started 1         0       3/5/2018
2         ended   0         1       3/22/2018   
3         started 1         0       3/25/2018
```

There are other events and columns for 0/1 but they are irrelevant.

I am trying to get how long it takes each user to get from started to ended.

I tried `datediff(day, case when started=1 then date end, case when ended=1 then date end)` but since they are on different rows it doesnt work. Something along the lines of datediff over() could work, but that is obviously not a valid function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK redshift supports `LAG`/`LEAD` or for two rows simply use MIN/MAX

Comment: Would you mind formulating an answer? I am abit confused as to how to implement your hint

Comment: It would look something like: `SELECT userid, CASE WHEN ended = 1 THEN datediff(day, date, lag(date) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY date) END as duration ...` Essentially the `lag()` will retrieve the same user_id's previous record's date field.

Comment: @JNevill the problem is the previous date will be for a different event- as mentioned there are other events in between, which I excluded to not clutter the view- sorry

Comment: Do you need 1 row per user_id as result or both rows, *started&ended*?

Comment: It is not possible to have 1 row per user due to the event column- which I need (so both)

Comment: You need additional columns? Otherwise MIN/MAX will return start & end date, too.

Comment: Can a user have more than one started and ended events?  If so is there a concrete way to group them together?  If not, is it possible to have two or more start events followed by two or more end events? if so which ones are matched pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can't *end* before you *started*, you simply need MIN & MAX as *Windowed Aggregates*:

```
select user_id, 
   datediff(day, 
            min(date) over (partition by user_id),
            max(date) over (partition by user_id))
from myTable
where event in ('started', 'ended')
```

Using this you can add any additional columns, too.

If one result row is also ok, you can do simple aggregation:

```
select user_id,
   min(date) as started, 
   max(date) as ended,
   datediff(day, 
            min(date),
            max(date)) as duration
from myTable
where event in ('started', 'ended')
group by user_id
```

Comment: Why not just use `group by`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Per comment OP wanted both rows

Answer (score 0):

You could inner join the table on itself using the `user_id` column:

```
SELECT a.[user_id]
     , a.[date] AS StartDate
     , b.EndDate
     , DATEDIFF(DAY, a.[date], b.EndDate) AS DateDifference
FROM dbo.TableNameHere AS a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT [user_id]
             , [date] AS EndDate
        FROM dbo.TableNameHere
        WHERE [ended] = 1
    ) AS b
        ON a.[user_id] = b.[user_id] 
WHERE a.[started] = 1
```

In my example above, you don't really need any of the columns in the first `SELECT` besides the `DateDifference`, I just had them for visibility in my testing.